# sqlite database prevents page to load ( ionic 3)

Tags: android, sqlite

I try to pass data from CapPage to ArchivesPage and insert them into sqlite database. According to the android console, it works. The problem is that the ArchivesPage doesn't load to display the database content. It's not a problem of navigation handling between pages because when I remove the code related to the database the ArchivesPage loads but empty.

Here is the cap.ts code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ArchivesPage } from    '/home/stephane/test_ionic/myApp1/src/pages/archives/archives';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'page-cap',
templateUrl: 'cap.html',
})

export class CapPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams:       NavParams) {  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad CapPage');
  }
openArchives(value) {
  console.log(value);
  this.navCtrl.push('ArchivesPage', value);

  }

}
```

Here is the archives.ts code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'page-archives',
templateUrl: 'archives.html',
})
export class ArchivesPage {
private db: SQLiteObject;
archives: any = [];
date;
duree;
distance;
FC;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams:  NavParams, private sqlite: SQLite) {
this.date=this.navParams.get('date');
this.duree=this.navParams.get('duree');
this.distance=this.navParams.get('d');
this.FC=this.navParams.get('FC');

this.createDatabaseFile(); 
this.insertWorkout();
this.displayWorkout();

}

ionViewDidLoad() {
console.log('ionViewDidLoad ArchivesPage');
console.log(this.date);
}

/*ionViewWillEnter(){
    //this.archives = this.archivesService.getArchives();

}*/

private createDatabaseFile(): void{
this.sqlite.create({
  name: 'dataSports.db',
  location: 'default'
})
  .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {

    console.log('Bdd créée !');
    this.db=db;
    this.createTables();

  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
  }

private createTables(): void{
this.db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cap (idCAP INTEGER NOT  NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, date TEXT NOT NULL, duree TEXT NOT NULL,  distance INTEGER NOT NULL,FC INTEGER NOT NULL)', {})
.then(() => {
  console.log('Table created!');
  this.insertWorkout();
})
.catch(e => console.log(e));


}

private insertWorkout(): void{

this.db.executeSql('INSERT INTO cap (date, duree, distance, FC )  VALUES (?,?,?,?)',[this.date,this.duree,this.distance,this.FC])
.then(() => {
  console.log('archives insérée!');
  this.displayWorkout();
  })
.catch(e => console.log(e));

}
private displayWorkout(): void{
console.log("display lancée");
this.db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM cap', {})
.then((data) => {
  if(data==null){
    console.log('pas de données !');
    return;
  }
  if(data.rows){
    if(data.rows.length>0){
      console.log('des données !');
      for(var i=0;i<data.rows.length;i++){

        this.archives.push(data.rows.item(i).distance);
        console.log(this.archives[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  })

  }

  }
```

And the archives.html code:

```
<ion-header>

<ion-navbar color="danger">
<ion-title>archives</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content>
<ion-list *ngIf="archives">
<ion-item *ngFor="let archive of archives">
  <ion-label>{{archive}} </ion-label>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

The question is: how to display the data from the database in archives.html ? (I'm a beginner in ionic) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: I put

```
this.createDatabaseFile(); 
this.insertWorkout();
this.displayWorkout();
```

into ionViewDidLoad() and it works !